# Spring Social Facebook Plugin - HTTP Status 404 - /ssconnect/facebook

Tags: grails, spring-social

Integration with FaceBook and Twitter using the spring-social plugin are working properly locally, but when I deploy to production, both stop to work. No errors found at the log file catalina.out under Tomcat7.

Error is happening after I inform my password in Facebook, after that, Facebook is redirecting to an invalid page:

[my domain here]/ssconnect/facebook?code=AQC04UTDdGWFHR9AndhLf9hFzNE1pBgFlAzcYpmvFDwy6WkVDKuVxlcnbGi3TumBD2Jj3zVUVwaMOcDhfZ0PzfI1saAdS1cB5swafkrrYwMaczggC8wFpk09kkJJKB-whNwImyr427yBncFWF5QaZ_OgeJ22k9lRSZXJ4Kwl0avhfuRUr8Pni6LC-Cj4g_ZKRmA

Grails 1.3.7
spring-social-core 0.1.31
spring-social-facebook 0.1.31

I'm looking into this class: SpringSocialConnectController

Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. It's not a bug with the plugin at all (maybe the exception handling could be improved on it), it was a bad configuration on my side, see:

Change in Config.groovy:

**From:**

grails.serverURL = "http://mydomain.com"

**To:**

grails.serverURL = "http://**www**.mydomain.com/**[my subdomain]**"

- notice that the "www" made difference here.

After that, worked!